# Android: Does googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) will cost money?

Tags: android, location, currency

Is googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) counted as a service request? and will it cost money if the requests of fetching user location exceeds 150000?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't. It actually uses the device's GPS to determine the user's location.

Try running your application without internet connection. You may still see the blue coloured marker in the map.

Comment: i think u r right. it worked without internet. I was thinking it might be sending location to do any accuracy improvements over the server.

Answer (score 1):

The Google Maps API for Android does not have a usage limit: [Usage Limits](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#usage-limits)